# Suppress a Warning -python-pandas-colab_notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, warnings, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to normalize a three-digit country code column in a pandas df. I found a great function called `country_converter`, and I'am currently running this function on the country column in a very large dataframe. It's returning **thousands** of these warnings because there are `NaN` values present in the column.

> WARNING:root:nan not found in ISO3

I'm looking for two things:

1. to suppress the nan warnings specifically
2. to speed up the processing time of this function (my thought is suppressing the warnings should speed up the process; however, if you have any suggestions about trying something different with my code that would be great!

I've tried all variations of the name, but nothing seems to work so I think I'm missing something...

```
import country_converter as coco
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message= "nan not found in ISO3")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message= "root:nan not found in ISO3")
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", message= "WARNING:root:nan not found in ISO3")

test = pd.DataFrame({"code":[np.nan, 'XXX', 'USA', 'GBR', "GBR",'SWE/n', "123", "abs", "ABCC", "ABC", np.nan, np.nan]})


test['code_convert']= test["code"].apply(lambda x: coco.convert(names= x, to='ISO3', not_found= np.NaN))
```

Expected to see no more warnings with the `nan` value.

Comment: Why not apply the function to your column where values aren't null? Can we see your function?

Comment: I was thinking about that route, but I'm not sure how to go about that?? If I dropped the nulls how would I recombine them later? The code above is my actual code besides the variables names. Here's the code with my variable names: 
  ascent['country']= ascent["country"].apply(lambda x: coco.convert(names= x, to='ISO3', not_found= np.NaN))

Answer (score 1):

I've adjusted your data in your dataframe to make the np.nan proper np.nan's and not strings.

```
test = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "code": [
            np.nan,
            "XXX",
            "USA",
            "GBR",
            "GBR",
            "SWE/n",
            "123",
            "abs",
            "ABCC",
            "ABC",
            np.nan,
            np.nan,
        ]
    }
)

print(test)

     code
0     NaN
1     XXX
2     USA
3     GBR
4     GBR
5   SWE/n
6     123
7     abs
8    ABCC
9     ABC
10    NaN
11    NaN
```

Then all you need to do is filter out the np.nan when doing your calculation.

```
test["code_convert"] = test[test.notna()].apply(
    lambda x: coco.convert(names=x, to="ISO3")
)
```

I don't have country converter installed but if I simplify the apply to test:

```
test["code_convert"] = test[test.notna()].apply(
    lambda x: x + "_solution"
)

print(test)

     code    code_convert
0     NaN             NaN
1     XXX    XXX_solution
2     USA    USA_solution
3     GBR    GBR_solution
4     GBR    GBR_solution
5   SWE/n  SWE/n_solution
6     123    123_solution
7     abs    abs_solution
8    ABCC   ABCC_solution
9     ABC    ABC_solution
10    NaN             NaN
11    NaN             NaN
```

Comment: SUPER basic question... does this filter out my NaNs indefinitely? because I wanted to imput them after I used this country converter.

Comment: The issue with your code appears to be that your "NaN" were strings, not numpy.nan. np nan is special and handled as a blank space. Your string nan appears as if a country code so you get an error when you query the database of countries.. I think. Not sure if that answers your question?

Comment: I feel like i haven't understood your question correctly, could you expand on your needs for the NaNs if my previous comment doesn't answer your question? Thanks.

Comment: So I basically just want to suppress the warnings to let the country_converter do it's thing and turn all invalid country codes into np.nans. I apologize my "example code" was incorrectly coded with "NaN" instead of np.nan (still a learning newbie), but I'm just wondering why I can't seem to suppress the warnings even though I think I'm entering it correctly.

Comment: There's a section called "Handling missing data" in the country code documentation about half way down the page [here](https://github.com/konstantinstadler/country_converter/blob/master/doc/country_converter_examples.ipynb).